# Using html input pattern in awk

Tags: regex, awk

`echo 8d07\'54.520\"W | awk '{ if ($1 ~ /[-+]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+/) print $1; else print "erro" }'`

I'm trying to check if it's a number, but it's no working... I use this same regex in a html 
input text, and it works.

In this case I was expecting "erro". It's not working.

My final goal is to apply 3 different pattern match to 3 fields $1 $2 $3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure of the requirement but you probably need to put anchors.

```
$ echo 8d07\'54.520\"W | awk '{ if ($1 ~ /^[-+]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+/) print $1; else print "erro" }'
erro
```

Comment: It doesn't validate in the same way... I don't understand.

Comment: Without anchors `^` your regex matches any part of your `$1` and prints it. If you need to match, you have to tell the regex to start looking from the start of `$1` and not anywhere in between `$1`

Comment: OK! I'm trying to understand. In html input this is done by default...
This is the correct pattern [-+]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+ because with your if you put one digit it gives erro

Comment: I'm reading this more carefully http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

This a more complete pattern for number.

Comment: The $ at the end is very important the patter like this worked!

^[-+]?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+$

Thanks

Comment: @apinhal Great. Both `^` and `$` are anchors. That makes sure that we are matching the whole field and not just part of it.